# getJSON not pulling data across domains

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to pull data using the jQuery getJSON method across domains. I have setup a test on JS FIDDLE here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kbPV7/1/

I really have no idea why this is not working. If I upload this file on the same domain or use feeTest.html locally, the code works.

However, if I upload or use the truly intended URL the feed does not work.

Also, if I use .ajax in the same domain it works. But it was my understanding that .ajax does not work across different domains and that is what the .getJSON is used for.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: No, `.getJSON` is for retrieving JSON data from the same domain. jQuery will automatically parse the data into a JavaScript data structure. If you want to make cross domain calls, you have to use JSONP (which you can use `.getJSON` for as well), which has to be supported by the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.getJSON()` is a shorthand to a `.ajax()` with preconfigured options. See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

The data in the URL are in the JSON format and that is not supported cross-domain. They need to be returned in the JSONP format which means that they must be able to put the data into the specified callback function.

You must either modify the service to use JSONP and allow you to specify callback parameter or use other ways how to access the service.

An example of using [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) to access your data:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
  data: { 
    q: 'select * from json where url="http://www.corporatereport.com/SampleSites/rockwellCollins/mockup5/feedTest.html"',
    format: 'json'
  },
  dataType: 'JSONP',
  success: function(data) {
    // this is the XML in JSON format
    console.log(data.query.results.json.news);

    // example - display list of titles
    var titles = $.map(data.query.results.json.news, function(news) {
      return '<li>' + news.t + '</li>';
    });
    $('<ul />', { html: titles.join('') }).appendTo('body');
  }
});
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/ewiyed/edit#javascript,live)** is the code.

Answer (score 3):

`$.getJSON` does not resolve the [same origin policy restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), however, [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) does. But, this requires that the server send back a callback wrapping the json data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a case where you have access to two different domains you can control and you've got to make crossdomain call. So, this case is when you can't avoid it and you've got no control over returning the data in JSONP format.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";        
script.src='path to crossdomain source.js';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

lookupInterval = setInterval("function_to_call()", 1000);

var lookupCounter=0;

function function_to_call(){
    //give up after 5 times
    if(++lookupCounter == 5)
        return clearInterval(lookupInterval);

    try{
        var cities = GEO_DATA_2011_11_28.cities.city;

        //since we found our data, let's clean the interval call
        return clearInterval(lookupInterval)
    }
    catch(e){
        //do nothing, we are actually controlling the situation with the if condition at the beginning
    }
}
```

We define our data in the remote js file as var GEO_DATA_2011_11_28 = {} in JSON format. The trick here is that we are dynamically injecting a script file into the head part of our HTML. Since script blocks can load crossdomain scripts without problem, we can do it in a deferred way. Considering there might be delays loading the script, we are making calls to a function that checks the data we want to acquire.

This solution was necessary because there was no way to send data in JSONP so we depended on reading simple js files.

Answer (score 0):

Hy, 
this is against the same origin policy and is normally not allowed. 
Anyway there's a Plugin for jQuery which useres Yahoo Query Language YQL. I used it on my projects so far and it worked fine. 
Here's the link for the tutorial http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/